# OpenCV: bitmaps and individual pixel manipulation

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, image-processing

I've been working with OpenCV for Android lately, working with pre-processing an image for optical character recognition via Google's Tesseract library. One method for improving the image quality is to iterate through pixel blocks (~64x64) and apply a threshold based on the average intensity of the region.

I'm running into problems with iterating through the regions of the saved Bitmap. When I access `Mat.total()` I get the correct number of pixels in the image, but looping through based on `Mat.rows()` and `Mat.cols()` applies the threshold to huge regions of text, which forces me to iterate by one or two rows at a time. Is there another way to manipulate them that I'm missing? Did I initialize the Mat/Bitmap incorrectly? In an image with thousands to millions of pixels, I may get ~100 rows/columns to work with.

Here's what I have:

```
    // set the bmp to the correct type (just gets the original Bitmap in an asy
    Bitmap img = params[0].copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    // begin image pre-processing by applying threshold and inverting the colors
    Mat mat = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(img, mat);

    Imgproc.cvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Core.bitwise_not(mat, mat); // invert the colors for readability

    for(int row = 0; row < mat.rows(); row += 2) {
        for(int col = 0; col < mat.cols(); col += 2) {
            Mat roi = mat.submat(row, row + 1, col, col + 1);
            // gets val[0] because there is only one channel to work with in the
            // grayscale image
            double averageIntensity = Core.mean(roi).val[0];
            // apply the threshold to this square minus a constant "delta" for leeway
            Imgproc.threshold(roi, roi, averageIntensity - THRESHOLD_DELTA, 255.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You said you want to process blocks 64 x 64 at a time, but it doesn't look like you're doing that in your code.  I don't quite see how a 64 x 64 block of pixels would be considered a large area of text.  Did you actually try finding the mean intensity of a 64 x 64 block and see the results?

Comment: I can't access the individual pixels. If I had a 1000x1000 pixel image, the Mat would have ~100 rows/columns to iterate through.